# phpDocumentor - Unable to find the dot command of the GraphViz package

Tags: symfony, composer-php, graphviz, phpdoc

I would like ask some help about my next problem:
I am working on a Symfony2 project. We installed Symfony2 via composer.
Now I would like to generate phpDocument used by phpDocumentor.

A did the following steps:

1. update composer: sudo php composer.phar self-update
2. add the following property to Symfony2/compose.json file:

   ```
   "require-dev": {
       "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*@dev"
   },
   ```
3. Run composer command

   ```
   sudo php composer.phar update
   ```

Result was success! The installed GraphViz version is: 1.0.2

When I try to generate phpDoc from source code finally I got a message:
*Unable to find the `dot` command of the GraphViz package. Is GraphViz correctly installed and present in your path?*
(Document generated as right...)

I tried to found a soulution about this problem but I couldn't.
Is anybody can help me to resolve this problem?

Environment is: Ubuntu release 12.04

Comment: Is **[graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)** really in your path ? What's the output if you invoke `which dot && echo "dot is my path" || echo "dot is not in my path"` ? :)

Comment: dot is not in my path! How can I set it? Thx!

Comment: where/how did you install graphviz? You need to make sure the folder containing graphiz's executables is listed in your `$PATH` environment variable. Otherwise you can just symlink the executables to some folder that's already in the path (i.e. `/usr/bin` ) with `ln -s`, too. The **[graphviz package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/graphviz/filelist)** usually installs them to `/usr/bin` ... so normally a simple `apt-get install --reinstall graphviz` should do the trick.

Comment: oh! I think I start to understand the probelm. Sorry...i am new in Ubuntu environment developing :) So I used install Symfony2 composer as I wrote above. Graphviz found: Symfony/vendor/phpdocumentor/graphviz. So I have to make a symlink usr/local/bin folder...I try it! Thx

Comment: [phpdocumentator/graphviz](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/GraphViz) is a php wrapper vor graphviz but not the actual executables. Symlinking any of these files to `/usr/bin` won't solve the issue. Install the graphviz ubuntu package `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install graphviz`

Comment: I followed your instrotuctions....and IT IS WORK! So i am very very grateful! One more think! Would you be so kind to write the solution a couple rows as a normal answer....i would like to accpet your answer and help! Thx a lot!

Comment: Thank you @NicolaiFröhlich. it works for me too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Graphviz is a nice software that creates graphs, but PHP software can only provide wrappers that create Graphviz source files that then get parsed and morphed into pictures.

Phpdocumentor comes with it's own wrapper, but you still have to install the Graphviz software package.

Comment: On Mac you can install it via Homebrew: `brew install Graphviz`

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu just run

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
```

rerun phpdoc, at the end you will see the line

```
Execute transformation using writer "Graph"
```

that's all!

Answer (score 2):

The error says that : **[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) tool (needed for making charts and graphs in the documentation) is not installed, in that scenario you will have to download the suitable version and configure it ! And if you are sure that it is installed on your system, then you should check whether the command `dot` is available or not.** On windows `path` `environment variable` needs to be set which makes the `dot` command execution to be available from any path. Fixing this may get your things working !

Comment: Hey, can you explain how to configure it step by step please ?

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows**

Follow the steps below to resolve this error are:

1. download Windows Packages from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html
2. Just install it
3. add c:\Program Files\Graphviz*\dot.exe or c:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz*\dot.exe to your environment variable PATH
4. run phpdoc
5. Re-start your machine & run phpdoc (if still shows the same error message)

Answer (score 1):

For windows 7/10 just install https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/ select the Stable install packages. Then add

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin

to your system environment variables. Make sure to change the version to the one you downloaded.

To check if it works open a new instance of cmd or git bash and run **dot**. If it says dot is not a valid command then make sure the path to Graphviz bin folder is correct.